# Tomcat Hot Deployment of Json Files

Tags: java, json, tomcat

I have a Tomcat installation that serves some Json files placed in "classes" folder of webapp folder. i need a way to make tomcat reload them after any changes cause it seems it reads them from a cache or something. it is not a production setting and is used for testing anyway.
I managed to do it with management console of tomcat and with "Reload" button. but isn't it another way?

Comment: I should note that the app is initially deployed using a WAR file.it is extracted by tomcat to the folder i change files in.

Answer (score 0):

set attribute autoDeploy=true of host element in /conf/server.xml.